# How to make panel in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

Does anyone know how to do panels like in the image below?

I tried to make cards but it is not like in the image
[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjzUX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/v2pyduqh/9/)?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myfiddle">
  <div ng-controller="BaseCtrl">

<div class="list card">
    <div class="item item-divider">Credit Limit
        <a href="#" class="item-icon-right">
            <i class="icon ion-minus" ng-click="toggleGroup(group)"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-body">
        <ion-content>

      <div id="search-bar">
        <div class="item item-input-inset">
          <label class="item-input-wrapper" id="search-input">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="myfiddle" ng-click="search()">
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="list card">

        <div class="item item-avatar">

          <div class="circle positive-bg">
            <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
          </div>
          <h2>20000</h2>
          <p>Available</p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="list card">

        <div class="item item-avatar">

          <div class="circle positive-bg">
            <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
          </div>
          <h2>20000</h2>
          <p>Used</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="list card">

        <div class="item item-avatar">

          <div class="circle positive-bg">
            <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
          </div>
          <h2>20000</h2>
          <p>Limit</p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="list card">

        <div class="item item-avatar">

          <div class="circle assertive-bg">
            <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
          </div>
          <h2>20000</h2>
          <p>Overdue</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myfiddle', ['ionic']).controller('BaseCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.exclamation = 'rocks';
      $scope.search = function() {
        alert("search");
      };
    $scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
        group.show = !group.show;
      };
    });
```

CSS:

```
ion-card.cards-list-demo ion-card-header {
  color: #387df5;
}

ion-card.cards-list-demo a > icon {
  color: #444444;
}

.item-avatar > div.circle:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
  max-width: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 2% 3%;

  color: #ffffff;
}

.floatright {
  float: right;
}

.list.card {
  border-top: 3px solid blue;
}

.item.item-avatar h2, .item.item-avatar p{
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-bottom:1px;
}
```

Comment: yes .I thought I could do this without css.just html tags specific for ionic